# CSS - Div must fit content AND break line

Tags: css

Is there a way to make a div element fit its content AND break the line, so that the next element is under that div?

I´ve tried to set the `display` property to `inline-block`, but then the div doesn´t break the line anymore... By default, it breaks the line, but doesn´t fit its content.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example so people can understand more easily?

Comment: Here´s the example: http://jsfiddle.net/A6n2h/ I want that the box fits the text when hovering an element. Without changes on the html structure.

Comment: If you wanna [do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33511762/274502) with jQuery, you could write something *like* `$('#id container').each(function(){ $(this).parent().width($(this).width()); });`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to do it without an extra div, I don't think there's a way.  Here's how with 2 divs:

```
<div>
  <div style="background-color: #FF0000; display: inline">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this buddy?

[http://jsfiddle.net/A6n2h/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/uFDK5/1/)

I used this CSS code:

```
.container div *{float:left; display:inline-block; clear:both;}
```

There was a few errors in your HTML code too.

Comment: This does not help when you look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/uFDK5/  I don't want that files are side by side